# T-Mobile (AT&T also) Account Balance

Tags: php, curl

I am looking for a way to query the webserver in order to request the available amount of money in the account. I am trying using cURL right now but I am having difficulties making a POST request (the webserver is blocking me ...).

Is there any API or direct command?

Comment: You might want to read their EULA as scraping sites like this is often against their policies, it can get your account locked/banned or your IP blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver blocking your request is a good indicator that you're trying to do something they don't want you to do.  Most likely what you're trying to do is against the end user license agreement (thanks, TravisO). I don't really know of a case where scraping a site is allowed for an EULA.

However all is not lost! T-mobile has a customer API you can use: https://capi.t-mobile.nl/ and AT&T also has an API: http://developer.att.com/